# Not able to display json array in li tag using angular js

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, html, api

I want to extract couple of parameters from json response but somehow I am not able to populate it. I am using angular js and third party api.
This is my API result. I just want to display "[{"severity":{"label":"Severe"},"label":"Skin Rash"}]" out of entire array. I need to populate in html in list view.

"an allergy has one or more reactions.  each reaction has a severity.  label Severe is a key in the Severity object.  label Skin Rash is in the reactions object.  the allergy object has it's own label field."

{"reactions":[{"severity":{"label":"Severe"},"label":"Skin Rash"}],"audit":{"source":"medicare","createDate":"2015-03-02T18:39:23Z","updateDate":"2015-03-02T18:39:23Z","version":"1"},"label":"Other - IODINE","ended":"2007-10-28T00:00:00-04:00","started":"1993-01-01T00:00:00-05:00","date":"2015-03-02T18:37:42Z"}

Comment: I want to know what you have tried  until now and which part of the resulting code you have had problems in.

Answer (score -1):

Use ng-repeat:

Not sure what you are looking for, but here is an example:

EDIT

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){

var obj = {"reactions":[{
"severity":{"label":"Severe"},
"label":"Skin Rash"}],
"audit":{"source":"medicare","createDate":"2015-03-02T18:39:23Z",
"updateDate":"2015-03-02T18:39:23Z","version":"1"},
"label":"Other - IODINE","ended":"2007-10-28T00:00:00-04:00",
"started":"1993-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
"date":"2015-03-02T18:37:42Z"}

  $scope.reactions = obj.reactions;

});
```

In your index.html; you can do the following

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <th>Severity label</th>
        <th>Just Label</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in reactions">
          <td>{{item.severity.label}}</td>
          <td>{{item.label}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Here is the Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/sgJ9RvtUYl6DkUDXPCc6?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with the syntax which you mentioned here.I am able to display object but not actual value. "[{"severity":{"label":"Severe"},"label":"Skin Rash"}]". How can I display actual value. like "Skin Rash"

Comment: Check if inserting "label" in the reactions array works.

Comment: If I am using reactions[0].severity then it is displaying only "Severe" but I want to display "Skin Rash". Close call but not getting it.

Comment: item.reactions[0].severity.label   <--this might work

Answer (score -1):

This should work!

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data.reactions">
        {{item.label}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.data = {
    "reactions":[
        {
            "severity":
            {
                "label":"Severe"
            },
            "label":"Skin Rash"
        }
    ],
    "audit":
    {
        "source":"medicare",
        "createDate":"2015-03-02T18:39:23Z",
        "updateDate":"2015-03-02T18:39:23Z",
        "version":"1"
    },
    "label":"Other - IODINE",
    "ended":"2007-10-28T00:00:00-04:00",
    "started":"1993-01-01T00:00:00-05:00",
    "date":"2015-03-02T18:37:42Z"
};
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in data.reactions">
  {{item.label}}
</ul>
```

Comment: It tries, but it does not! At first it just repeats the 'ul' instead of an 'li'... Further he wants to contain the label of "severity"... And last but not least, if an answer to a question starts with "try that" you could bet on that it should be a comment instead...